# Unable to access the root directory via SFTP explorer (Nemo)

Tags: nautilus, nemo

I am connecting via sftp inside nemo but if I try to access the root of the server I get the `Location is not a folder`... but I am pretty sure it is :p

Other destinations are perfectly fine:

`sftp://bulletboys/etc`

How can I access the root? I am logged in as `root` user.

[image]

Comment: FTP will start in the HOME of a user. Root will have /root as its home so ftp probably expects it at /root/bulletboys/ And please for the safety of your machine use a non-root account and use your /home/$USER/ to download and upload through ftp. There is absolutely no reason to let go of basic security.

Comment: It seems that, as I was connecting via a password. I was not able to access `/` since changing `PasswordAuthentication no` I am now able to access `/`. Thank Rinzwind

Comment: Funny thing is, I could connect to the FTP root (just the address of the server with no path in the URL) once and since disconnecting it once it refuses to accept the FTP root as a directory. \[EDIT]: Even funnier: I restarted nemo without disconnecting from the FTP and now I can access the FTP root again.